# Best way to render passes off different objects?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, render-layers, render-passes

I have a full detail version of a model and a less detailed version. For style reasons, I want to render my diffuse pass off the full detail model, and my gloss pass off the low detail version.

I know I can achieve this by putting the two objects on separate render layers or scenes, then combining them in the compositor. However, this requires me to render two separate layers or scenes.

Is there any way to do that does NOT require rendering twice? It seems that perhaps you could use light paths or something to make one of the objects only take diffuse and the other glossy or something, but I haven't been able to figure it out.